# Update an API URL using AJAX when user selects from datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How can I make my `dateDates` variable update with **AJAX** when the date picker button is applied? `apply.daterangepicker` is the triggered when the apply button is clicked

See the snippet below, but effectively, I am using http://www.daterangepicker.com (Date Range Picker that relies on Bootstrap, jQuery and Moment.js) to allow the user to update a date period, outputting...

```
let dateDates = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ',' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```

And `dateDates` is passed to a **API** as...

```
$.getJSON(`https://examples.com/?module=API&method=API.get&date=${dateDates}&format=json`, (data) => {
```

note the `${dateDates}` within `date=` of the **API** as when date picker button is applied I want these values to update and reload the **JSON** data with the new URL.

See full code in this snippet. Cheers.

```js
$(function() {

  var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
  var end = moment();

  function cb(start, end) {
    $('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));
  }

  $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  }, cb);

  cb(start, end);

  let dateDates = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ',' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');

  $.getJSON(`https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dateDates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`, (data) => {
    let visitors = 0;
    let uniq_visitors = 0;
    let pageviews = 0;
    let uniq_pageviews = 0;
    let actions = 0;
    let outlinks = 0;
    let bounces = 0;
    let avgtime = 0;
    let dayCount = 0;

    for (i in data) {

      if (data[i].nb_visits) {
        visitors += data[i].nb_visits;
      }
    }
    $("#visitors").html(visitors);
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />

<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<div id="reportrange" style="background: #fff; cursor: pointer; padding: 5px 10px; border: 1px solid #ccc;">
  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;
  <span></span> <b class="caret"></b>
</div>

<div id="visitors"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get your question, but from what i understand, you need to place your code to get your json in a callback as second parameters of your daterangepicker function.

```
 var start = moment().subtract(29, 'days');
 var end = moment();
 let dateDates = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ',' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'); 
 let defaultUrl = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dateDates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`; 
 updateValueForUrl(defaultUrl);
 $('#reportrange').daterangepicker({
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end,
    ranges: {
      'Today': [moment(), moment()],
      'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
      'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
      'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
      'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
      'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
    }
  }, function(start, end) {

    let dates = start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ',' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD');
    let url = `https://discovrbookings.innocraft.cloud/?module=API&method=API.get&format=json&idSite=2&period=day&date=${dates}&token_auth=68aa5bd12137f13255dcb98794b65dff`;
    updateValueForUrl(url);
  });

  function updateValueForUrl(url) {
    $.getJSON(url, (data) => {
        let visitors = 0;
        let uniq_visitors = 0;
        let pageviews = 0;
        let uniq_pageviews = 0;
        let actions = 0;
        let outlinks = 0;
        let bounces = 0;
        let avgtime = 0;
        let dayCount = 0;

        for (i in data) {
          if (data[i].nb_visits) {
            visitors += data[i].nb_visits;
          }
        }
        $("#visitors").html(visitors);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Sorry Nicolas, in the most basic terms. I want the JSON URL and data on the page to be reloaded with upon a user entering another date. It defaults as `last 30 days` but if that is changed I need the data to update with the new JSON.

Comment: Your answer most definitely works in updating the value but loses the default value. Just trying to get that back now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Darren I will edit my answer to provide a default value support.

Comment: @Darren this way, you get the default value once, and every time the value of the daterangepicker changes.

Comment: Cheers @Nicolas. This is perfect - had many charts within this script and amazed this worked out the first time for all. I just need to put back the `$('#reportrange span').html(start.format('MMMM D, YYYY') + ' - ' + end.format('MMMM D, YYYY'));` but this was a great solution. Thanks again.